# Paypal recurring payment for german payers

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to integrate a recurring payment from PayPal with the express checkout, but it seems that it doesn't work with payers from germany.
If I test with a sanbox user which is set to the united states, everything works fine, but if I try to do that with my sanbox user which is set to germany I get an error that "We cannot procceed the request. Please got back to the store an chose another option".

Have anyone a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Recurring payments cannot be created for buyers in Germany or China. In this case, you can use reference transactions as an alternate solution.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/?mark=IPN%20notification